# When using function_score in Elasticsearch, does it matter if filters are inside or out the function_score object?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I'm looking at some old code and whether it is necessary to refactor it for performance.

The thinking is... with function_score you're applying a function to all the documents you want to return, SO, if you can only run those functions on the documents you need, that would be better.

Currently the way this is done is a bit like this (I've simplified the query to discuss here):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          },
          "functions": [
            {
              "gauss": {
                "updated_at": {
                  "origin": "now",
                  "scale": "7d",
                  "offset": "2d",
                  "decay": 0.5
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "indexed": true
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "sale_stage": [
                    "on_hold",
                    "withdrawn",
                    "off_market"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    "_uid"
  ],
}
```

The contents of the query is not important. What is important is that there are filters OUTSIDE the function score.

The query runs fine, and returns the correct data. HOWEVER, am I right in thinking that the score functions are being run on ALL the documents in the index AND THEN being filtered, OR is ES clever enough to optimise here since it knows I want a filtered set of data?

In other words, can I leave the query as is, OR should it be turned into this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": {
                "match_all": {}
              },
              "filter": [
                {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "indexed": true
                        }
                      }
                    ],
                    "must_not": [
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "sale_stage": [
                            "on_hold",
                            "withdrawn",
                            "off_market"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "functions": [
            {
              "gauss": {
                "updated_at": {
                  "origin": "now",
                  "scale": "7d",
                  "offset": "2d",
                  "decay": 0.5
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "_score",
    "_uid"
  ],
}
```

In the 2nd example, the intention of the query is the same, but I've moved all the filtering INTO the scoring function. The reason being, if I have a very expensive function (like geo spacing stuff) I don't want to run it on every document.

Do I need to make this small refactor or is it unnecessary because ES optimises for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave the filters outside the `function_score` query. The idea being that if you have several `function_score` queries, the filtering is only done once and then all the function scores are run on the filtered data set.

Also, if you have aggregations in addition to your `function_score` queries, then definitely let the filters outside so that aggregations can be computed on a reduced document set as well. Filters are all about reducing the document set on which costly computations need to be run.

Comment: Yes Val thank you. I wanted to mark it as the answer when you answered but couldn't and then forgot to come back to our 